# Spin lock and try finally block in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Why release a spin lock in finally block?
In `LongAdder.class` the spin lock `cellsBusy` is released in `finally` block, but there are no resources or statements that will throw an exception in `try` block, so what is the purpose of release a spin lock in `finally` block.
I guess when a thread is about running out of its cpu time, JVM will try to run all statement in `try` block and then release resources in `finally` block, so the `cellsBusy` lock can be released before a thread release cpu.
If I comment `finally`, It seems sometimes some threads may hold this lock very long.

```
                  if (casCellsBusy()) { // CAS lock
                     try {
                        if (cells == null) {
                            cells = cs;
                        }
                     } finally {
                        cellsBusy = 0;  // free lock
                     }
                  }


                     if (casCellsBusy()) { // CAS lock
                        if (cells == null) {
                            cells = cs;
                        }
                        cellsBusy = 0;
                     }
```

Comment: In this case, it seems unnecessary.  I would suppose it's a stylistic convention - every time the spinlock is used, there is a 'finally' to release it.  Your guess about JVM behaviour is unfounded.

Comment: I tried many time before when I commented try finally, it sometimes works badly. but I retried just now, everything goes ok, I think you are right, it a stylistic convention. @danglingelse

Comment: I do not think it is "stylistic". There could be `OutOfMemoryError` at `new Cell[2]`

Comment: It is not about releasing any resources. Writing 0 to the `cellsBusy` variable, which is declared as `volatile`, will ensure that all the writes performed on the cells array are visible after the loop. It is an optimization to avoid unnecessary `volatile` writes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I uploaded pictures which has code in it, but someone tell me not to upload pictures, so I changed it to text and mis-added `new` into `try`. There is no `new` actually and I have updated the `try` statement just now. @AlexanderPavlov

Comment: My English is not very well, actually I want to know if the `try finally` is necessary, and if it is ok to comment the `try finally` block and release the lock out side the `finally` block. @alchemist

Comment: if there is no `new` then it is more about structuring code. If it is not in `finally` then someone could add new row after `cellsBusy=0`. Using of `finally` tells future editor that this code must be executed after all.